# Open window with several tabs in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I somehow open window with several tabs in it after clicking on div? Browser doesn't matters, any solution would be acceptable (even browser settings changing).

Comment: You mean real browser window with a few physical tabs? It's not possible via JS.

Answer (score 2):

You can not control the creation of the browser's tabs. You can only open new windows.

The behavior of tabs and windows can be configured in each browser in a different way and there's no way to take control of it right now.